# Javascript wait until localization resources are pulled from server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript code:

```
(function (document, window, $) {
    'use strict';

    var Site = window.Site;
    var translations = [];

    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        translations = Site.getTranslations();
        Site.run(); // glogal site setup
    });

    // Init function
    // ------------------------
    (function () {

        $("#cbolanguage").change(function (e) {
           
            // start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: url.switchLang,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ lang: e.target.value }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    if (data.success) {

                        location.reload();
                    } 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }, complete: function () {

                }
            });

        });

        function init() {

            $('#btn-login').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $('#form-login').data('formValidation').validate();

                if (!$('#form-login').data('formValidation').isValid()) return;

            });

            init();
        }


    })();


    // Validataion
    // ------------------------
    (function () {
        $('#form-login').formValidation({
            framework: "bootstrap",
            icon: null,
            fields: {
                Login: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: translations.text1 // NEED TO WAIT UNTIL THIS HAS A VALUE
                        }
                    }
                },
                Password: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: translations.text1 // NEED TO WAIT UNTIL THIS HAS A VALUE
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            err: {
                clazz: 'text-help'
            },
            row: {
                invalid: 'has-error'
            }
        }).on('err.field.fv', function (e, data) {
            data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
        })
            .on('success.field.fv', function (e, data) {
                data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
            });;
    })();

})(document, window, jQuery);
```

In the `document.ready()` I call the function:

```
 translations = Site.getTranslations();
```

This function code is:

```
  getTranslations: function () {
          var returnData = [];

         // start ajax request
         $.ajax({
             url: appData.getTranslations,
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             dataType: "json",
             async: false, // SYNCRONOUS CALL
             success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                 if (data.success) {
                     returnData = data.data;
                 }
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 
             }, complete: function () {

             }
         });

          return returnData;
      },
```

The problem that I have is that on my main javascript all the functions, including the form validation are executed without waiting for the translation object to get a value.

I need to wait for all my functions until the call to get the translation resources to finish.

Any clue?

Comment: Could you expose a *promise*, so other things can `whenTranslationsLoaded.then(() => /* do stuff */)`?

Comment: Yes I could, any clue on how to do this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify your 'getTranslations' function and use await where you are calling it.Like this :

```
    getTranslations: function () {

     // start ajax request
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       $.ajax({
         url: appData.getTranslations,
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: "json",
         async: false, // SYNCRONOUS CALL
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

             if (data.success) {
                 resolve(data.data);
             }
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             
         }, complete: function () {

         }
       });
     });
  },
```

Now await this call in your document.ready() function.

```
  (function (document, window, $) {
     'use strict';

      var Site = window.Site;
      var translations = [];

      $(document).ready(async function ($) {
         translations = await Site.getTranslations();
          //change your immediately invoked functions into named functions
          // and call them here              
          initialisation();
          validation();


         Site.run(); // glogal site setup
      });

      // Init function
      // ------------------------
     function initialisation() {

      $("#cbolanguage").change(function (e) {
       
        // start ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: url.switchLang,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ lang: e.target.value }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                if (data.success) {

                    location.reload();
                } 
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }, complete: function () {

            }
         });

        });

        function init() {

         $('#btn-login').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#form-login').data('formValidation').validate();

            if (!$('#form-login').data('formValidation').isValid()) return;

         });

         init();
        }

      };


      // Validataion
      // ------------------------
     function validation() {
       $('#form-login').formValidation({
        framework: "bootstrap",
        icon: null,
        fields: {
            Login: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: translations.text1 // NEED TO WAIT UNTIL THIS HAS A VALUE
                    }
                }
            },
            Password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: translations.text1 // NEED TO WAIT UNTIL THIS HAS A VALUE
                    }
                }
            },
          },
          err: {
            clazz: 'text-help'
          },
          row: {
            invalid: 'has-error'
          }
        }).on('err.field.fv', function (e, data) {
         data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
       })
        .on('success.field.fv', function (e, data) {
            data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
        });;
    }

  })(document, window, jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes. It was added in the ES2017 spec.

Comment: Seems to work but just to wait from translations = await... to Site.run(), the other functions insdie the main javascript are executed. So maybe that is needed is some when( after that and call the other functions but dont have a clue how

Comment: You can change your immediately invoked functions into named functions. Now call these functions after waiting for translations inside the 'document.ready'.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, would you mind to update the post just with a simple example because dont know what you mean about "named functions". Thanks a lot

Comment: Appreciate so much

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: What I saw is that when having async here:  $(document).ready(async function ($) it never gets inside the function... do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it never gets inside the function"? Which function are you talking about ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the case, because i mimicked a similar example on my machine and its working with async. Also you commented earlier that  - "Seems to work but just to wait from translations = await..." . It won't be possible if program execution didnt enter document ready function.

Comment: Can you do a console.log in document ready function and check if its working. It might be possible that some other part of your code is breaking.